# Foursquare & apigee: Incorporate likes in venues search

Tags: foursquare

i'm using Apigee to get some foursqaure data.
Unfortunately, with this query:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=48.137743,11.579949

the like quote (as in "9 of 10 people like this place")

is not incorporated. Ive tried out inserting &likes in the query, but i don't get there.

Does anybody the answer? I need the 50 results with likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like count isn't something that Foursquare exposes in search or explore results. However, once you have the venue you want to retrieve likes for, you can make a second request to either [venues/likes](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/likes) or [venue detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) to retrieve like counts. If you're making many requests, consider using a [multi](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/multi/multi) request.